# Passing server URL through properties file not working in apache http client

Tags: java, http-status-code-404, apache-httpclient-4.x, properties-file

I am trying  to read a url through properties file and passing into  the apache http post constructor.when I did this I am getting 404 error and when hard code it,it is working fine.I don't know what is the difference between two approaches. After reading from properties file  i am printing the variable on console,it is showing the exact url,but I am getting '404 not found' when i passed the same string variable in http apache client.Can anyone guide me on this.Thanks

Reading URL :

```
    requestURL = MWTConfiguration.getInstance().getValue("NPCI_AUTH_URL");
                System.out.println("Request URL :"+requestURL);
                objAuthRequest.setPid(objFITransXTRequest.getPid());
                objAuthRequest.setRbd(""); 
 authResponse =objMWTHttpClient.execute(strRequestJson, requestURL);
```

Client Code :

```
public String execute(String requestData, String strURL) throws ParseException, Exception {
        String strResponse = "";
        StringBuffer objSBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
            System.out.println("URLLLL : :"+strURL);
            HttpPost reqFundTransf = new HttpPost(strURL);
            StringEntity params = new StringEntity(requestData);
            reqFundTransf.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            reqFundTransf.setEntity(params);
            HttpResponse objResponse = httpClient.execute(reqFundTransf);
            HttpEntity objRespEntity = objResponse.getEntity();
            BufferedReader objBReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(objRespEntity.getContent()));

            while ((strResponse = objBReader.readLine()) != null) {
                objSBuffer.append(strResponse);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
        return objSBuffer.toString();
```

Console View :

```
URLLLL : :http://223.30.66.28:8080/AEPSNPCI/rest/aepsauth/authentication
2017-03-14 16:08:27 DEBUG RequestAddCookies:122 - CookieSpec selected: best-match
2017-03-14 16:08:27 DEBUG RequestAuthCache:75 - Auth cache not set in the context
2017-03-14 16:08:27 DEBUG PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:219 - Connection request: [route: {}->http://223.30.66.28:8080][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
2017-03-14 16:08:27 DEBUG PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:250 - Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {}->http://223.30.66.28:8080][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
2017-03-14 16:08:27 DEBUG MainClientExec:217 - Opening connection {}->http://223.30.66.28:8080
2017-03-14 16:08:27 DEBUG HttpClientConnectionOperator:120 - Connecting to /223.30.66.28:8080
2017-03-14 16:08:27 DEBUG HttpClientConnectionOperator:127 - Connection established 10.9.31.135:44782<->223.30.66.28:8080
2017-03-14 16:08:27 DEBUG MainClientExec:238 - Executing request POST /AEPSNPCI/rest/aepsauth/authentication HTTP/1.1
2017-03-14 16:08:27 DEBUG MainClientExec:243 - Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2017-03-14 16:08:27 DEBUG MainClientExec:249 - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2017-03-14 16:08:27 DEBUG headers:124 - http-outgoing-0 >> POST /AEPSNPCI/rest/aepsauth/authentication HTTP/1.1
2017-03-14 16:08:27 DEBUG headers:127 - http-outgoing-0 >> content-type: application/json
2017-03-14 16:08:27 DEBUG headers:127 - http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Length: 729
2017-03-14 16:08:27 DEBUG headers:127 - http-outgoing-0 >> Host: 223.30.66.28:8080
2017-03-14 16:08:27 DEBUG headers:127 - http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
2017-03-14 16:08:27 DEBUG headers:127 - http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.4 (java 1.5)
2017-03-14 16:08:27 DEBUG headers:127 - http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
2017-03-14 16:08:27 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 >> "POST /AEPSNPCI/rest/aepsauth/authentication HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
2017-03-14 16:08:27 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 >> "content-type: application/json[\r][\n]"
2017-03-14 16:08:27 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Length: 729[\r][\n]"
2017-03-14 16:08:27 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: 223.30.66.28:8080[\r][\n]"
2017-03-14 16:08:27 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
2017-03-14 16:08:27 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.4 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
2017-03-14 16:08:27 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
2017-03-14 16:08:27 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
2017-03-14 16:08:27 DEBUG wire:86 - http-outgoing-0 >> "{"modality":{"fp":true,"otp":false},"uidNumber":"496640436689","rrn":"707316193975","pid":"YUVIL7CKWbBjFV+UCZBKGMnLJeHSNJjrZ6r+0kyfMZl0VEKNeIHyeaXFPLsYXyxJ9qISBTPmN/4qrS82AT781Q\u003d\u003d","rbd":"","hmac":"XuVPiZ9kLxHSAzxzyFqu+eY18F1bQVqOzjbGF7Pc21L2ohIFM+Y3/iqtLzYBPvzV","ci":"20170227","sKey":"lrq66RF9C0H00tFVA3MjRRui0NFyM/1BlYxfJkzHFZhrWaLt1xpUd7M1z1skeXqJwNmB7Ygcyht22Tqr701eHSiZTKWl6N4gJLDr4EZjDB+OYqDTg28qSiHC3/TDvASr9m+F0ymKZhAdw7aASf+ZCxpkdjBOI/FzaIlTo67r9azYeVKPd/53bnpOvboxUdpt0coI8ElheTArcE5xQVDVC3Y5iJYkARjVgRonrjWSLlb0D9WzZ2Aolq2vnwo7nnglb0uqiqanUUrStqK//MNcVq5R5acu5hZv83XZNH0m/4v1+Ku3zQp0Kuc6nRNkE0M6f+LKZJ8JlkeSnIwoubFA1Q\u003d\u003d","metaData":{"udc":"AX20123","pip":"10.230.23.24","lot":"P","lov":"244221"}}"
2017-03-14 16:08:27 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found[\r][\n]"
```

Comment: can you `curl` that URL ?

Comment: curl? What is this can you please tell me

Comment: any useful link to read about curl?

Comment: can you POST anything to that endpoint using any other means?

Comment: yes, by using postman I can hit and get response and also by hard coding the url in http post  constructor

Comment: It could also be your `*. properties` file encoding at play here.  Can you verify what encoding is used in your properties file?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Trim Function there might be a white space either in end or in start of string.

`HttpPost reqFundTransf = new HttpPost(strURL.trim());`

Comment: Did you try URL encoding and decoding?

Answer (score 0):

try changing it to backslash.

You might have be missing escape character for forward slash in your url mentioned in properties file.

try using '\/' before forward slash.

Comment: sorry I am not able to understand how to use this '\/'

Comment: if you have url as below in properties file:

http://223.30.66.28:8080/AEPSNPCI/rest/aepsauth/authentication

try changing it to

http:\///223.30.66.28:8080\//AEPSNPCI\//rest\//aepsauth\//authentication

Comment: I did it, but getting the same response 404

Comment: try adding one more slash at the end of authentication. As connection is getting established but just that post request /AEPSNPCI/rest/aepsauth/authentication HTTP/1.1 is getting failed.